# How do I check how many times a term has occured in a list and its frequency?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, function

`text=["duran duran sang wild boys in 1984","wild boys don't remain forever  wild","who brought wild flowers","it was john krakauer who wrote in to the wild"]`

For example in this list `"duran"` is in 1 sentence and has occured 2 times in `text[0]`

For seperate codes first output should be `1` and second output should be `2`

I tried functions with `.count` and `.check` but couldn't make a proper code.

Comment: What do you mean by "For seperate codes first output should be 1 and second output should be 2"?

Comment: @np8 there are seperate codes first code should output how many sentences the word is in (ex: duran is in 1 sentence) second code should output word's frequency in the sentence(s) (ex: second code gathers information that duran is in 1st sentence and checks how many "duran"s are in that sentence which is 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code counts all occurencces of a `word` in all strings in a list of lists `l` and also returns the number of list elements containing this `word`.

```
text=["duran duran sang wild boys in 1984","wild boys don't remain forever  wild","who brought wild flowers","it was john krakauer who wrote in to the wild"]

def countInListOfLists(l, word):
    counts = [s.count(word) for s in l]
    return sum([1 for c in counts if c > 0]), sum(counts)

print(countInListOfLists(text, "duran"))
```

Output:

```
(1,2)
```

Comment: how do i make it repeat for this output ? 
    def get_unique_words(a):
    visited = set()
    uniq = []
    for word in a.split():
        if word not in visited:
            uniq.append(word)
            visited.add(word)
    return uniq


def get_unique_words_from_list_of_strings(str_list):
    return get_unique_words(' '.join(str_list))


words_in_order = get_unique_words_from_list_of_strings(text) print(words_in_order)

Comment: To clarify: first, you want to apply `get_unique_words` to each list in `l` and then want to count?

Comment: `countInListOfLists` need to be applied to `text` for every word in `words_in_order`   without me typing print(countInListOfLists(text, "")) everytime

Comment: I didn't use your function but you can do something like this: `uniqueText = set((" ".join(text)).split(" "))
print([countInListOfLists(text, word) for word in uniqueText])`. (a `set` doesn't contain duplicates by design)

Answer (score 0):

you could accomplish it with the following code.

```
# check how many times a term has occurred in a list and its frequency
def count_occurrences(lst, term):
    return lst.count(term)

# check the frequency of term in a list
def frequency(lst, term):
    return count_occurrences(lst, term) / len(lst)
```

Additionally, I am assuming you would split your list elements in advance to create a list of words rather than a list of sentences, which adds complexity. Otherwise, see the @CLRW97 response.

Split your list into words:

```
# split list of sentences into list of words
def split_sentences(lst):
    return ' '.join(lst).split()
```

As a result, you will have three clean functions at your disposal:

```
# split list of sentences into list of words
def split_sentences(lst):
    return ' '.join(lst).split()

# check how many times a term has occurred in a list and its frequency
def count_occurrences(lst, term):
    lst = split_sentences(lst)
    return lst.count(term)

# check the frequency of term in a list
def frequency(lst, term):
    lst = split_sentences(lst)
    return count_occurrences(lst, term) / len(lst)

text=["duran duran sang wild boys in 1984","wild boys don't 

remain forever  wild","who brought wild flowers","it was john krakauer who wrote in to the wild"]

print(count_occurrences(text, "duran"))
print(frequency(text, "duran"))

> 2
> 0.07407407407407407
```

However, for a more straightforward answer, check out @DannyMoshe is response, which appears to be rather intelligent as well. Mine is simply deconstructed into a few functions to make the code more understandable while also reducing its complexity by utilising builtins/simple Python functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as a one liner -

```
wordCount = len([word for word in (' ').join(text).split(' ') if word == 'duran'])
```